# How does reactjs proptypes work under the hood?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm interested to know how reactjs `PropTypes` work under the hood as I would like to implement something similar in an application I'm writing.

Specifically, I'm trying to create property validators in the same format as reactjs (i.e `{type}.{isRequired}` syntax).

Additionally, I hope to do it so that only *one instance* of each validation function exists at a time.

My current implementation is as follows:

```
// Interface
class PropTypes
{
    static string(isRequired)
    {
        return isRequired ? 
            ConcretePropTypes.string_required : 
            ConcretePropTypes.string;
    }
}

// Concrete prop validation
class ConcretePropTypes
{
    static string(x) { return typeof x == "string"; }
    static string_required(x) { return !isNan(x) && this.string(x); }
}

// Sample usage
var propTypes = { name: PropTypes.string(true) };
```

...but this demands the usage of arguments (i.e `isRequired`) to determine which validation function to return. As it is not intuitive what the boolean argument being passed in represents (unless the source code is looked at), I would prefer to use a syntax similar to reactjs - i.e `string.isRequired` - so that it removes any ambiguity in its usage.

All in all, what I'm looking for is information on how reactjs proptypes work and as such, how I can apply this to my own code. If the question title is misleading and needs changing, please let me know.

Comment: WThe best way to find out how it works is to look at the source code. Have you done that? https://github.com/facebook/prop-types

Comment: @FelixKling I haven't. I will do so now